# Firing Server Side Event from jQuery - __EVENTARGUMENT Does not Exist

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am trying to fire a form submit via jQuery and have a particular server side event fire.

Client Side Code:

```
$("input[name=__EVENTARGUMENT]").val("SomeArg");
form = $("body form");
form.submit();
```

Server Side Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] == "SomeArg")
            {
                //do some stuff
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is, the "__EVENTARGUMENT" hidden input does not exist. I discovered that if I add an ASP.net server control dropdownlist with autopostback = true, the EVENTARGUMENT hidden input is created. Is there a cleaner way to have ASP.net create these hidden inputs, and allow me to get their values server side without adding controls I do not actually need on the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add asp.net [HiddenField control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwesd2s9%28VS.85%29.aspx) to the page

But you will have a problem which is to get this control id, which as.net generates automatically, you can solve this using the ClientID property for the hidden field like [this article mentions](http://blog.jagregory.com/2006/04/12/how-to-use-clientids-in-javascript-without-the-ugliness/)

Comment: I added a 'test' HiddenField control to the page. The EVENTARGUMENT hidden field was not auto-generated. I'm wary about creating one with that name since that javascript/page load code is actually on a user control. The user control may be placed on pages that have an autogenerated EVENTARGUMENT hidden field or pages that do not have that control autogenerated.

Comment: why you need this special EVENTARGUMENT ?

Comment: AH! Did not realize that all named input fields were accessible through the Request object. THANKS!